Python webscraping for websockets
I want to extract the information when the tyre from below link will be in stock. I have around 10 pages that I want to monitor by checking the availability of them.
I don't want to use the selenium and would prefer to use requests for it.
It gets the request token by sending a POST request StockHub/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1
After this it send web socket request.
https://www.jaxtyres.com.au/tyres/hankook/ventus-s1-evo2-k117?sku=ha2254517k117w
Error Message:
"error":"Handshake was canceled.
Tried:
import websocket
import json

def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message)

def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)

def on_close(ws, close_status_code, close_msg):
    print("### closed ###")
    print(f"Close status code: {close_status_code}")
    print(f"Close message: {close_msg}")

def on_open(ws):
    params = {
        'id': 'D9lTUVj1e2K55TYd58EYJA',
    }
    ws.send(json.dumps(params))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://www.jaxtyres.com.au/StockHub",
                                header=headers,
                                on_message=on_message,
                                on_error=on_error,
                                on_close=on_close)
    ws.on_open = on_open
    ws.run_forever()

Can you please help?

What is the content of headers?

@Hanstjua
headers = {     'Pragma': 'no-cache',     'Origin': 'https://www.jaxtyres.com.au',     'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',     'Sec-WebSocket-Key': 'ygLHM1tLqVOHOxXgnMHCTw==',     'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/126.0.0.0',     'Upgrade': 'websocket',     'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',     'Cookie': cookie_string,     'Connection': 'Upgrade',     'Sec-WebSocket-Version': '13',     'Sec-WebSocket-Extensions': 'permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits', }
